# Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsEndpointAutoConfiguration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I am a novice Java Spring programmer. I am moving some test code from an older jHipster project to a new one. I added this to the pom.xml to fix a compilation error. This fixed my compilation issue but caused runtime errors.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I am now getting these runtime errors.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.MetricsEndpointAutoConfiguration
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.MetricsEndpoint]

```
 <spring-boot.version>2.2.5.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
```

If I remove spring-boot-actuator

> incompatible types: java.time.Instant cannot be converted to java.util.Date
> cannot access org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter
> method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Does anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Is the version correct? Try after removing the version tag from the dependency, the correct version will inherit from the `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

Comment: I am using spring 2.2.5. If I remove the version from the dependency then the compile errors return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with the dependency. First, do not specify the version unless you are very sure there won't be any dependency conflicts. This is one reason `spring-boot` is so popular that you need not to worry about dependencies and their compatibility. Let `spring-boot` handle that. The compatible version will inherit from the parent.

The other issue is, why use `spring-boot-actuator`? you should be using the `spring-boot-starter-actuator`

Here's a sample pom

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

And then in `dependencies`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <!-- Spring will find the version compatible with the parent -->
</dependency>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The issue is I am moving old code into the new. The old code is a different version. So I need both versions.

Comment: did you try with `spring-boot-starter-actuator` instead of `spring-boot-actuator`?

Comment: Yes. It already has that. I get errors from the old code if I remove the spring-boot-actuator. see above.

Comment: Why is `spring-boot-starter-actuator` preferred to `spring-boot-actuator`?